# Weird issue with ngClass in angular2

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template

Angular is forcing me to use the class name in single-quote even my css class name does not have any hypens. This is so weird that I tried everything but seems angular is obssessed with hypen for this specific css class...weird OR I am doing something wrong ??

Following is my html template file,

```
<div [ngClass]="'box'">
    <header [ngClass]="header">{{header}}</header>
    <ng-content [ngClass]="body"></ng-content>
       <footer [ngClass]="footer">{{footer}}</footer>
</div>
```

following is my css file,

```
.box{

   border: 1px black solid;
   background-color:yellow;
}

.footer{

 background-color: green;

}

.header{

 background-color: green;
 text-align: center;

}
```

and following is the component file,

```
import {Component,Input,Output}  from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector:'message-box',
  templateUrl: './error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error.component.css']
  })
export class ErrorComponent {

    @Input() header:string = 'header from child';
    @Input() footer:string = 'footer from child';

}
```

Comment: Who added negative on this question and why ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `[ngClass]="box"` it will think that `box` is a property on your component. That is why you need `[ngClass]="'box'"`.

But why use `ngClass` if it won't change?

```
<div class="box">
    ...
</div>
```

FYI the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) show that one of the parameter types is a string literal, as you have done.

Comment: but I am using the css class as string in the <header> and <footer> element. it works just fine ( you can see in the code-snippet above) but exact same way, when I am trying to apply 'box' class on <div> , suddenly I am being forced to use single-quote.... you see a difference in the <header> element and the top <div> element by any ways ??

Comment: sorry, now I got your point **"If you do ngClass="box" it will think that box is a property on your component"** ,  wondering how angular2 resolve the css class when I put  it in double quotes as in the case of <header> and <footer> element  as it is assuming "header" as a property in my TS class which is present but angular is **NOT** taking this as a css class ( but as a TS class property), even though it does end-up applying css class right ??

Comment: For the header and footer, the CSS class that ends up on the DOM element should be the strings in your component like "header from child". Is that what you see? As for how Angular knows how to parse inputs to components - I guess it checks to see if you are passing an object literal, array literal, string literal, etc. If it sees a word or function call instead, it tries to find it on your component. But I don't know the parsing details (like if it's all done by Regex, for example). You could check the source code for that :)

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate it in details ( when I will get some time) and will post it in this thread for the reference.